# sum() on specific columns of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I cannot work out how to add a new row at the end. The last row needs to do sum() on specific columns and dividing 2 other columns. While the DF has applied a filter to sum only specific rows.

df:

```
    Categ    CategID    col3      col4      col5      col6
0   Cat1     1          -65.90    -100.40   -26.91    23.79
1   Cat2     2          -81.91    -15.30    -16.00    10.06
2   Cat3     3          -57.70    -18.62      0.00    0.00
```

I would like the output to be like so:

```
3   Total              -123.60   -119.02    -26.91    100*(-119.02/-26.91)
```

col3,col4,col5 would have sum(), and col6 would be the above formula.

If [CategID]==2, then don't include in the TOTAL

I was able to get it almost as I wanted by using .query(), like so:

#tg is a list

`df.loc['Total'] = df.query("categID in @tg").sum()`

But with the above I cannot have the 'col6' like this `100*(col4.sum() / col5.sum())`, because they are all sum().

Then I tried with Series like so, but I don't understand how to apply filter .where()

```
s = pd.Series(  [df['col3'].sum()\
                ,df['col4'].sum()\
                ,df['col5'].sum()\
                ,100*(df['col4'].sum()/df['col5'].sum())\
                ,index = ['col3','col4','col5','col6'])
df.loc['Total'] = s.where('tag1' in tg)
```

using the above Series() works, until I add .where()
this gives the error:
`ValueError: Array conditional must be same shape as self`

So, can I accomplish this with the first method, using .query(), just somehow modify one of the column in TOTAL ?
Otherwise what am I doing wrong in the second method .where()

Thanks

Comment: Shouldnt it be `100*(-119.02/-26.91)` ? and not `100*(-119.02/-26.01)` btw what is `tg` ?

Comment: tg is a list of ints. Ive done the calc in my head, as example, this is irrelevant of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can try:

```
s = df.mask(df['CategID'].eq(2)).drop("CategID",1).sum()
s.loc['col6'] = 100*(s['col4'] / s['col5'])
df.loc[len(df)] = s

df = df.fillna({'Categ':'Total',"CategID":''})
```

---

```
print(df)

   Categ CategID    col3    col4   col5        col6
0   Cat1       1  -65.90 -100.40 -26.91   23.790000
1   Cat2       2  -81.91  -15.30 -16.00   10.060000
2   Cat3       3  -57.70  -18.62   0.00    0.000000
3  Total         -123.60 -119.02 -26.91  442.289112
```

Comment: Can you please show how to do it with `[CategID in tg]`, as I don't know what ids will be used, this is provided dynamically.

Comment: @michal try `s = df.mask(df['CategID'].isin(tg)).drop("CategID",1).sum()`

Comment: thank you, your answer resolved my issue.